# how do i restrict root user from using running certain commands

Tags: bash, shell, root

I broke my linux system while running `mv /*` from a directory.

I want to restrict the use of `/*` `*` mostly as an argument to certain commands like `rm` and `mv`.

I want to filter this argument using my `~/.bashrc`. I know of the restricted bash shell `rbash` but I am not quite okay with only that as I have changed my current default shell for root.

If I am to capture the argument `$0`, `$1` from the command like
then write an `if` conditional statement which would perform some steps and warn the user. Would the  implémentation work if I place the script in my `~/.bashrc` file or are there other better methods I am missing?

i need someone to point me in the write direction.

thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: The obvious question, of course, is why are you logging in as root? There are _dozens_ if not hundreds of commands that can break your system if you run them as root. Limiting the use of `*` would protect from very few of those, and would make using the system much harder (`*` is pretty essential).

Comment: I don't think you'd even see `*`, it will be expanded to something before you inspect it.

Comment: i only login as root when i need extensive access, sudo always asks for password over a short period of time . what if i can narrow it down to stuffs like `mv *` `mv /*` `rm /` `rm /*` just for move command rmdir command. will other program relying on it still break.

Comment: yes `*` will be expanded for the currend working dir but still a dangerous glob string

Comment: just change the `mv` command to `xmv` then create a script which will call `xmv` with an if statement in that script which checks for `/*` or `*` or `/`.

just use the mv command to `mv` the `mv` command to `xmv`
create script called `mv` with the hashbang `#!sh` then do the checks, etc...then mark as executable and volia

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen The shell will expand `*` before calling your script, so you will see the list of files instead of `*`.

Comment: @Bodo https://stackoverflow.com/a/11456496/6651840

Comment: @technophile just disable the wildcard using `set -f` or see link in previous comment of mine

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen thanks alot wizard. i didn't think of such idea in mind. i an sure your answer will work. the `set -f` - disables wildcards, would it  be workable if i appended it to the root user `~/.bashrc`

Comment: Don't ever login as `root`. `root` login was replaced by `sudo` for good reasons decades ago. Learn to use `sudo`. Read `man sudo sudoers`. In general, take more care when issuing commands. Unix/Linux is a powerful tool, but can be used to shoot yourself in the foot. Don't.

Comment: it's not uncommon to have aliases like `alias mv='mv -i'` and `alias rm='rm -i'` to make it difficult to make mistakes like this.  The `-i` forces interactive mode, and asks you if you want to move/delete each file.   `-i` can be over-ridden by using the `-f` option, so even with the alias you can still run `rm -f *`.

Comment: The **BEST** thing you can do, though, is to get into the habit of double-checking your commands **before** you hit enter, especially if they are using potentially dangerous programs like `rm` or `mv` or `dd` (or thousands of others, anything can be dangerous when run as root.  they can also be dangerous to your personal files when run as your normal user account).   Carelessness and haste destroy more data and kill more systems than anything else...probably more than **everything** else combined.

Answer (score 0):

In Unix, `root` is all-powerful. Just as Unix provides the user with enough rope to shoot their feet off, so can do `root` hose the whole system.

The *only* solution is to be extra careful. Get accustomed to read and check each command twice, specially if potentially destructive. Think carefully whenever you mess with some system piece, perhaps go as far as setting up a test environment under e.g. Docker to try out stuff. Have instalation media handy, and know how to use them for rescue purposes. Keep backups. Store important stuff in a version control system, so there are older versions to fall back to or in dire circumstances grab a remote copy.

Answer (score 0):

i really thank you for your advice @Nasir Riley and all others who have contributed to this question. i have learned a lot.

i stumbled upon a post that restricts the use of * or /*
`set -f noglobber`

i have also configured saferm on my system and to most part i only use sudo

but i have an this `set -f noglober` does not work on zsh

Comment: If this is a follow-up question, then you may be better served by asking it as a new question rather than as an answer to a question.

Answer (score -1):

Use **sudo** instead of *root*, then you can set the permissions you wish in the *sudoers* file.

If you don't want to type a password everytime you use the sudo command, *(and I know you don't because in your comments you said, "i only login as root when i need extensive access, sudo always asks for password over a short period of time")* then add the NOPASSWD to the sudo line: i.e.,

```
## Same thing without a password
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: That would allow the user to `sudo su -` and become root which isn't what is wanted.

Comment: You didn't really read the answer; I said they could modify the sudoers file to prevent access to whatever file they wish. To prevent access to *sudo su -* the line would be ```%wheel ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL, !/bin/su```

Comment: @NasirRiley there's never any point in that. If you want to open a root shell you can use `sudo -s` or `sudo -i`, you don't need to run `su` with `sudo`! Shōgun8, I don't see how this would help. The OP can still run `sudo rm *` and you can't restrict the usage to disallow `*` through `sudoers`. All you could do is block the use of `rm` and `mv` which would render the system almost impossible to administrate. The only thing you actually show in your answer (passwordless `sudo` for everything) will make the OP _less_ safe, not more.

Comment: And those can be disabled too. You shouldn't suggest that running things as root is better than using sudo; that's bad practice. The OP wrote that he is trying to avoid typing the password often which is why he *is avoiding using sudo altogether*.  Use sudo, make it passwordless, and lock it down

Comment: I never suggested that running things as root is better. My point is that i) you are not locking anything down here, on the contrary, you are making everything more open and ii) the OP wants to be protected from inadvertently running `rm *` or `mv * foo` and that is not something you can affect through the `sudo` system. Whether they use `sudo` or open a root shell makes no difference here.

Comment: You ARE actually suggesting that somehow using sudo is less secure than using root. The OP is trying to figure how to disable deleting files with a wildcard as root. I am suggesting to not do that, as that is a really bad idea, because it is a bad idea to use root for anything. It is better to use sudo, and I am trying to suggest that as the answer. You are impliciitly suggesting that the OP should use root instead because of all the bad things that can go wrong with sudo, ironically.

Comment: @terdon I know. It doesn't matter how it's done, if the point is to not allow the user to open a root shell, then the answer isn't the way to do it. Rather than putting that as the contents, it needs to have a list of the commands that can be run as root. It's not that I disagree with your point, it's just that the answer isn't viable.

Comment: @Shōgun8 Yes, I did read it as did whoever downvoted it. Your answer would allow someone to just run as root which isn't what is wanted. If that was wanted, then there wouldn't have been any need for the question. Perhaps you should put what actually mean in your answer rather than something that isn't applicable.

Comment: It actually doesn't allow someone to "just run as root" as you put it. If sudo were the same as root, then why does sudo exist? why not just login as root? Well my guess is that if you just login as root, then you cause damage to your system by possibly deleting whole directories with a single command. So wise admins will always suggest running dangerous commands as *sudo* so that the danger can be blunted by restricting the power of the sudo user.

Comment: **@Nasir Riley**, If you read carefully you will see that the actual question is how to *prevent* the deletion of files while ***running as root***. The OP stated in comments that he wishes to avoid using the *sudo* command simply because he doesn't ***llike to type his password in very often***. My suggestion is to *not run as root*, and it shows how to use *sudo* without typing in the password very often. Read it again.

Comment: @Shōgun8 I know what the question said. I can read. Your answer isn't valid because it allows a user to open a root shell which isn't necessary to do what is needed and that's probably why it was downvoted and has no upvoted. As has been stated, it wouldn't make sense to allow someone to run commands like `rm` or `mv` as sudo anyway because it can effectively render a system unusable. That's exactly what happened. What the questioner wants to do isn't viable anyway as warning the user wouldn't necessarily stop them from running a command that destroys the system.

Comment: @ Nasir Riley, precisely why suggesting he run those commands as *sudo* is prudent advice, addresses the reason he's running things as root; he doesn't realize that sudo can be made to be passwordless so he chooses to use root instead of sudo..